# Chrome refresh right-click reload options not available

Tags: google-chrome, reload, browser-cache

I'm trying to do a `hard reload and empty cache` in Chrome because a previously loaded site keeps coming up on the `localhost` port I'm using.

The problem is the right-click options seem to have stopped working, ie. nothing happens when I right-click on the refresh button and I can only left-click and reload the page normally.

I had the option before so I know it's not the Chrome version I am using. It's pretty annoying. Does anyone know what's happening here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Just figured out the basic reason for this - **Developer Tools Console must be open** to access right-click options on the browser refresh button.

There are two ways to do this. The quickest way is to press `F12`. You can also right-click anywhere on the page and select `Inspect`.

I guess it is a feature mostly just for developers and the Chrome team doesn't want regular users accidentally clearing their cache!

Comment: If you still can't right-click, make sure you have dev options opened for the correct window and tab. If you have several instances same app/site open it's an easy thing to overlook. Personally, I think if dev options are opened on any windows/tab on chrome, advanced user interface should be available on all of them

Comment: THanks alot @mikeym. I spend alot time to found what can be problem! Some times i have right-click options but another time i dont have that option. Problem is becouse  Dev Tools not opened. Deam... :D

Answer (score 14):

Press **F12** to open the developer tools and then you can **right-click** the reload button, and you get three options - **Reload**, **Hard Reload** (redownloads images) and **Empty Cache and Hard Reload**.

Answer (score 10):

I do have Dev Tools open in Chrome. For the past week or so, right-click no longer works on the toolbar button with the tooltip 'Reload this page, hold to see more options'. Workaround: Left-click to refresh the page and once the page reloads, Right-click on the same toolbar button and the menu appears now.

Comment: I think that Dev Tools has to be open when you first refresh or navigate to the page to enable the menu

Answer (score 1):

In order for the right-click > empty cache and hard reload option to show, dev tools must be opened AND the mobile view icon must be selected in dev tools (toggle device toolbar), then it should work.

Comment: This has already been said in the 3 other answers, whats the point of this?

Comment: No one else mentioned choosing the mobile view icon. These steps worked for me.

Comment: @Boom100100 It works fine for me without having the mobile view icon selected.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer as of September 18, 2023**: Open the dev tool by pressing F12, HOLD the SHIFT key and left-click on the refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 2023: Left click and HOLD. You can't right click on it any longer.